# Transition probability matrix, weather changes

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process, transition-matrix

I am trying to solve the following problem:[image]

and the probability that there will be three sunny days in a row specifically. I know that the answer is $1/5$ but I am trying to figure out how to get this answer. Since I do not know what weather it is the 23 december, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: The sentence "under the assumption that there is still a lot of time before Christmas" is a way of hinting that the weather in 23rd of december will be distributed according to the stationary distribution.

Comment: @E-A thanks, I solved it now!